# ionic - No target devices/emulators available

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

L launch command 'ionic cordova run android --verbose', I add --verbose option for more details , now I found this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC7ye.png)

and when I launch ionic serve, the application works but I have a problem cordova_not_available in browser

code config.xml:

```
      <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <widget id="fr.grdf.astuce.recette" version="1.5.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
      <name>Astuce</name>
      <description>Application permettant de connaitre le personnel GRDF d'astreinte pour les interventions d'urgence.</description>
      <author email="carma@grdf.fr" href="https://book.carma.grdf.fr">Carma</author>
      <content src="index.html" />
      <access origin="*" />
      <access origin="http://localhost:8080" />
      <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" />
      <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
      <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
      <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
      <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
      <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
      <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
      <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
      <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
      <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
      <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
      <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
      <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
      <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
      <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
      <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
      <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
      <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
      <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
      <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#2e9bff" />
      <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
      <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
      <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
      <platform name="android">
          <engine name="android" spec="11" />
          <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="33" />
          <preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
          <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
          <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
          <allow-intent href="market:*" />
          <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
          <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
          <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
          <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
          <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
          <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
          <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
          <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
          <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
          <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
          <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
          <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
          <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
          <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
          <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
          <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
          <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
          <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
      </platform>
      <allow-navigation href="http://172.17.167.132:8100" />
      <allow-navigation href="http://10.0.59.1:8100" />
      <allow-navigation href="http://10.0.0.8:8100" />
      <allow-navigation href="http://172.17.167.64:8100" />
      <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
      <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.4" />
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.3" />
      <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^6.0.0" />
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.3" />
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter" spec="~1.1.3" />
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="~5.0.0" />
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~3.0.0" />
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^5.0.0" />
  </widget>
```

how to fix error in picture please

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to open android studio to and create an emulator. the [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v6/developing/android) provides a guide on how to build for android.
2. Cordova plugins don't work on the web.

Comment: I don't have android studio but i installed android sdk with command line ,and also i installed cordova platform android with commande ionci cordova platform add android